# Transformar romano a número normal en Python (POO)

Tags: python, poo

Necesito determinar correctamente como convertir número romano a número normal con POO en *Python*:

```
class Romano:
    def __init__(self, roman):
        if(type(roman) != str):
            ## VAR IS NOT STRING ##
            raise ValueError('El numero romano ingresado no es valido!')
        elif (roman != roman.upper()):
            raise ValueError("Ingrese numero romano en MAYUSCULAS!")
        self.roman = roman
        self.normal = self.convert_to_normal()
    
    def convert_to_normal(self):
        romanos = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,
                   'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        entero = 0
        i = 12
        valor = self.roman
        for i in range(len(valor)):
            if romanos[valor[i]] > romanos[valor[i - 1]]:
                entero += romanos[valor[i]] - 2 * romanos[valor[i - 1]]
            else:
                entero += romanos[valor[i]]
        return entero
```

No me devuelve bien los números... por ejemplo necesito que me devuelva 11 que es efectivamente XI pero me devuelve 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema:

El problema esta en que no compluebas si el bucle está en el primer indice o `i=0`, lo que hace que la comparación se haga con el primer y el ultimo elemento de tu lista:

```Python
if romanos[valor[i - 1]] < romanos[valor[i]]:
```

Que es lo mismo que:

```Python
if romanos[valor[-1]] < romanos[valor[0]]:
```

Porque i vale 0 y el calculo se dá `0-1` lo que dá como resultado que la comparación se haga con el `ultimo < primer elemento`. Imaginemos que ingresamos VI, la comparación seria: `I<V` y eso no es lo que queremos.

### Solución:

Solo debemos bloquear el primer indice:

```Python
if romanos[valor[i - 1]] < romanos[valor[i]] and i!=0:
```

O simplemente iniciando la variable `entero` con el valor romano del primer indice y despues iniciar el bucle en 1:

```Python
entero=romanos[self.valor[0]];
...
for i in range(1,len(valor)):
    if romanos[valor[i - 1]] < romanos[valor[i]]:
        entero += (romanos[valor[i]] - 2) * romanos[valor[i - 1]]
    else:
        entero += romanos[valor[i]]
```

### Código completo:

```Python
class Romano:
    def __init__(self, roman):
        if(type(roman) != str):
            ## VAR IS NOT STRING ##
            raise ValueError('El numero romano ingresado no es valido!')
        elif (roman != roman.upper()):
            raise ValueError("Ingrese numero romano en MAYUSCULAS!")
        self.roman = roman
        self.normal = self.convert_to_normal();

    def convert_to_normal(self):
        romanos = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,
               'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000};
        i = 12
        valor = self.roman
        entero=romanos[valor[0]];
        for i in range(1,len(valor)):
            if romanos[valor[i - 1]] < romanos[valor[i]]:
                entero += (romanos[valor[i]] - 2) * romanos[valor[i - 1]]
            else:
                entero += romanos[valor[i]]
        return entero



print(""""Traductor de romano a entero:

0 - Para terminar.""");
while True:
    str__=input().upper();#Para evitar que se ingrese letras en minuscula.
    if str__[0]=='0':
        break;
    print(str__+"=="+str( Romano(str__).normal) );
```

### Enlaces:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRfb9owEH/3pzjgIcmgKO20F1geEKumSLSbgKJMCEUeOVprwWaOw1RN@@zs7ARoYNrZTny/O99fJ7tX86Lk@8NhnfOigKnacqkGDIgy3ECaCilMmvoF5pseaCsOKrElsfHN6w79CodWBIXRb@SWOh1YjKYQz@Dxyxxm82n8@JnAho7mokBY8LzEe62V9r37HGS5Ra0qnwqEfNZY8EwBMVjAnuciUy0vOBnCXGygCsVG4jb9crdD7QcXMV35a8fOPF44RQkPo29Ps/HTZDRrtc@@bDn6lavaU1Mkld7ynGSOWyu5R21So9JK4AdDdqrxtdQeehNxFUxB1n57sTeA2x54C3p/oHdi@bDXyI7Im1h5SApjp2B3nxxkdw8VFv45104am3YE4bm3xN3enViqt9LHhJoZb0ggqEFUVvmMfo7Sd9qXVaf21KksnXwp4AZuVyv4eIkTxmUGohWFg8vUjrF2o7rZjWM3cBfAu3/7aVjCvMD/2b4yfW4HmlLLWpUR7bSQxm8TzTXPyrWhemR4vEO81hwwFlIcX7nmQPxWSK77dIauwq8XkSPMdVlHRB9RmkZC7krjB8crPOy4o7gXhmv4WSK1ov4qEHI0mhf2vpLdsliXOe@zuubO2jJcRZEXeueUv2vkP4aOrRJwet12FLW7tPXrf0EFB/WNDiAYHg4xi@2ktWA0YppuEZAwGjFNuxYssdPtCU7csmiSuIcFJ4xGQtNKxyz8Cw)

Answer (score 3):

Una solución:

```
def roman2int(romval):
    total = 0
    prev = 0
    for letra in romval[::-1]:
        valor = romanos[letra]
        total += valor if valor >= prev else -valor
        prev = valor

    return total
```

La idea es recorrer el número romano de derecha a izquierda, examinando cada letra y agregando su valor particular al total en formación. La comprensión de lista con indices `[::-1]` es la forma de decir "recorrer de fin a principio".

El único detalle es que si la letra actual vale menos (`valor`) que la letra previa (`prev`, a la derecha en el original), el valor se resta en lugar de sumar.

#### Demo

```
romanos = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,
               'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}

def roman2int(romval):
    total = 0
    prev = 0
    for letra in romval[::-1]:
        valor = romanos[letra]
        total += valor if valor >= prev else -valor
        prev = valor

    return total

tests = ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "XIV", "CXC", "MIM"]

for test in tests:
    print(test, roman2int(test))
```

produce:

```
I 1
II 2
III 3
IV 4
V 5
VI 6
VII 7
VIII 8
IX 9
XIV 14
CXC 190
MIM 1999

Process finished with exit code 0
```