# ¿Por qué convertir romano a entero no funciona?

Tags: python, funcion

Vi este ejemplo en una clase de mi profesor, pero lo escribí en su momento y lo intenté replicar como me acordaba. Se trata de una función que recibe números romanos y devuelve números enteros.
numero_rom = input()

```
def rom_ent(romano):
  romanos = {"I":1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000}
  entero = 0
  for i in range(len(romano)):
    if i>0 and romanos[romano[i]] > romanos[romano[i-1]]:
      entero += romanos[romano[i]] - (2*romanos[romano[i-1]])
    else:
      entero += romanos[romano[i]]
    return entero
print(rom_ent(numero_rom))
```

El problema es que lafunción parece iterar solo una vez sobre la cadena ingresada; si ingresas X, te devolverá 10, pero si ingresas XX, te devolverá 10, de modo que no está leyendo el segundo caracter.
¿Alguien me podría explicar por qué? ¿Cómo arreglo esto?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Transformar romano a número normal en Python (POO)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495106/transformar-romano-a-n%c3%bamero-normal-en-python-poo)

Comment: Estás haciendo un `return entero` sin darle la oportunidad de iterar al bucle for. Siempre devuelve el valor del primer número romano que pilla.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el `return` mal indentado! Al tenerlo a la altura del `for`, la función retorna al primer ciclo de la iteración. La solución consiste en colocarlo donde corresponde, es decir, dentro de la función y a la vez fuera del ciclo `for`.

```py
def rom_ent(romano):
  romanos = {"I":1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000}
  entero = 0
  for i in range(len(romano)):
    if i>0 and romanos[romano[i]] > romanos[romano[i-1]]:
      entero += romanos[romano[i]] - (2*romanos[romano[i-1]])
    else:
      entero += romanos[romano[i]]
  return entero
print(rom_ent(numero_rom))
```